# Does Krampus only appear in the winter?

Tags: dont-starve

In Don't Starve, does Krampus only appear when it is winter?  Or can he appear in any season?

From what I've read about it, he appears to punish you for naughtiness.  I assume this is a nod to the [Krampus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krampus) of Northern European folklore . . . So, I wonder if he only appears during the winter?

I have yet to encounter him in the game, but perhaps I've just not gone on enough murderous rampages of innocent little bunnies.  (Mmmmmmm ... innocent little bunnies!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Krampus can appear in any season, provided the player's "naughtiness" is high enough.

Naughtiness is increased by killing innocent, i.e., non-aggressive animals. The amount of naughtiness received depends on the animal- killing baby animals and larger animals is naughtier than killing butterflies.

Naughtiness decreases by a small amount every minute if the player doesn't kill anything innocent.

Source: http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Krampus

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmm . . . innocent, non-aggressive animals.